# Change TinyMCE Block Format Labels

Tags: tinymce

For the sake of my site editors, I'm trying to rename the Headings in the TinyMCE dropdown.

I looked into filtering options but came up totally empty.

I've also tried a javascript solution but haven't gotten anywhere with that.

When I run `jQuery('#mce_4 a').text('Heading');` in the browser console, it works like a charm, yet when I put it into an javascript file and put it in the `.load()` function nothing happens. (The file itself is fine as it's running other functions already.)

If I run `console.log(jQuery('#mce_4 a'));` in my file, it comes up empty as if there isn't any DOM object matching that selector. The TinyMCE editor buttons are not in an iframe themselves, so that doesn't seem to be the issue either.

I would be thrilled with a PHP or JS solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the hook [`tiny_mce_before_init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) :

```
function wpse_106063_tinymce($arr){
$arr['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'h1,h2,h3,h4';

$style_formats = array(
    array('title' => 'title', 'block' => 'h1')),
// etc
);
$arr['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );


return $arr;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_106063_tinymce');
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** add something that should work, not tested. 
[source](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @JMa. That hook works great for changing what block formats are shown (and I'm doing that), but I don't think it can change the *labels* used for the block formats (e.g. "Heading 2") which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've edited code

Comment: Hmmm. That works to add an `h1` to the `styleselect` (separate from `formatselect`). I'm already using the `styleselect` for inline styles so it would be nice to leave the block formats in the `formatselect` drop down since those concepts (styles vs html block elements) are separate.

Comment: I guess it should be done in js

Comment: If only I could figure out how! Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated.